# Eclipse: why is CSS syntax highlighting not working consistently?

Tags: css, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-oxygen

I have a puzzling situation. Using Eclipse Oxygen.

One project, which I think I started as a Web Project in Eclipse Neon, does syntax highlighting for CSS files.

My new project, which I think started out as a PyDev Project here in Eclipse Oxygen, does not do highlighting for CSS files.

I'm unclear about the types of project because neither of the icons in Package Explorer (which are different) seems to correspond to any of the possible projects when you go `File` --> `New` (I've looked at all of them, including the icons under `Other`).

So it's really 2 questions: how do I find out what project type I'm working on... and how then do I configure the PyDev one (if such it be) to apply syntax highlighting to CSS.

Incidentally, the PyDev project is using a project location outside the default Workspace, not that this should make any difference.

Comment: Neon and Oxygen are different releases of the Eclipse ecosystem, but there's no guarantee that you've installed the same list of plug-ins in both. Did you actually install the same CSS tools in your copy of Oxygen?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't installed any CSS tools explicitly... and yet I have CSS syntax highlighting out of the box.  Just glanced at "installation details": the only Web-related one that I've installed is PDT (PHP Dev Tools).  NB this is a new machine and I've recently set it up and configured Eclipse, keeping a log of my installation/config actions...

Comment: PDT pulls in the HTML and CSS editors. It reuses much of the HTML editor.

Comment: @nitind see my comment in answer to your answer. Can you think of any way of getting (installed) PDT to recognise a CSS file in a PyDev project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation instructions can be found in the WTP Wiki at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F . Or you can use the Marketplace entry for it at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0 .

Comment: Thanks... I see this is "your baby" (I assume).  I tried to install by dragging the icon from the marketplace but this failed.  The Wiki entry says you have to install about 6 dependencies.  To do this just to get CSS syntax highlighting in one project seems a bit mad... but I may look into it later.

Comment: Failed how? And when you right click on the CSS file and go into its **Open With** menu, is it actually using the **CSS Editor**? Maybe it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier, I believe you were missing highlighting because the WTP tools weren't installed in your PyDev environment. Nevertheless, if you need to spend more than a few minutes working with CSS, I would encourage you to give CodeMix a try for truly superlative CSS support in Eclipse:

- Supports all the CSS 3 properties, including support for variables
- In-built Emmet integration reduces typing required
- Includes a CSS validator
- Sass and LESS supported too

For more, see: https://www.genuitec.com/tech/css3-in-eclipse/